# Error in conversion bigint to varchar SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, where

I am getting error SQL Errors occurred while processing retrieved data: Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

This my Query and its come from the where clause. Anyone help me to resolve this issue?

```
DECLARE @Inven VARCHAR(500)
SET @Inven = CONVERT(varchar,?)

SELECT count(tc.Name)
FROM Booking b
inner join BookingPassenger bp on bp.BookingID = b.BookingID
inner join PassengerJourneyLeg pjl on pjl.PassengerID = bp.PassengerID
WHERE il.InventoryLegID in (select value from STRING_SPLIT(@Inven, ','))
```

here ? will  be = 12334,9899,343534

Thank you

Comment: This doesn't look like a Salesforce question, is it marketing cloud related?

Comment: Marketing Cloud is also Salesforce @Girbot ;-)

Comment: This is SQL QUERY in Boomi

Comment: Issue in where clause WHERE il.InventoryLegID in (select value from STRING_SPLIT (?, ','))
here i am getting Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is failing because you are trying to store varchar data into a field which has Int/BigInt as a datatype.
Do check your Data extension/ Table fields & their datatypes and the kind of values you wanted to store in those fields.
Use functions like convert/format in your query to resolve the issue but do check the datatype first.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_format.asp

Comment: Thank you. As you said I converted the value to varchar

Answer (score 1):

You can only do SELECT statements in SFMC.

While the engine is based on Microsoft Transact-SQL, not all functions are supported:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5

It doesn't list all that's possible.

And there are some differences between what's supported in [Query Studio](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FP3yFUAT&tab=e) and [Query Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5).